# На странице меток после переделок появились строки без перевода

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14203

> $count$ вопроса

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14204

> $count$ вопросов

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14205

> $count$ вопрос

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14211

> Это модераторская метка, которую может добавить только ♦ moderator.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14197

> Это обязательная метка. Каждый вопрос должен иметь хотя бы одну обязательную метку.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14210

> Это обычная метка. На каждом вопросе должна стоять хотя бы одна метка.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14201

> Изменить краткое описание этой метки